# Firebase push notifications is not triggering onMessageReceive on Android when the app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I don't send the **notification** object in the JSON request to the Firebase API, the onMessageReceive is triggered normally and my notifications work as intended, but, when I use the **notification** or the **android** object in the JSON that I send as params the onMessageReceive is not triggered when the app is in background.

I've been trying to debug this but I can't figure it out.

I have a simple class in my server that user Firebase API to send the push notifications.

In the params that I send to the server, I'm sending the following attributes.

```
"apns": {
    "title": title.nil? ? "Testing notification" : title,
    "body": body.nil? ? "This is a test push notification, liking it?" : body,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "sound": sound.nil? ? "enabled" : sound
  },
  "android": {
    "title": title.nil? ? "Testing notification" : title,
    "body": body.nil? ? "This is a test push notification, liking it?" : body,
    "sound": sound.nil? ? "enabled" : sound
  },
```

or the following for cross plataforms.

```
"notification": {
    "title": title.nil? ? "Testing notification" : title,
    "body": body.nil? ? "This is a test push notification, liking it?" : body,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "sound": sound.nil? ? "enabled" : sound
  },
```

This configuration is suggested by google in the following official documentation

[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidConfig)
The only way it actually works is when I DO NOT SEND the **notification** or **android** object and generate the notification with the data I send in the **data** attribute of the JSON object sended to the Firebase API

```
params = {
  "#{key}": to,
  # "apns": {
  #   "title": title.nil? ? "Testing notification" : title,
  #   "body": body.nil? ? "This is a test push notification, liking it?" : body,
  #   "mutable_content": true,
  #   "sound": sound.nil? ? "enabled" : sound
  # },
  # "android": {
  #   "title": title.nil? ? "Testing notification" : title,
  #   "body": body.nil? ? "This is a test push notification, liking it?" : body,
  #   "sound": sound.nil? ? "enabled" : sound
  # },
    "data": {
      "title": title,
      "body": body
    }
}.to_json
```

The notifications sent through the Firebase console don't work either.

¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Use Below Xml Code in andorid manifest**

```
  <service
            android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**Create MyFirebaseMessaginfService Class to recive Firebase Notification When App is close.**

```
   public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

}
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
    Const.FireBaseTokenID=token;
    Log.e(TAG, "onComplete:Service "+Const.FireBaseTokenID );
}

public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    getFireBaseID();
}

public static void getFireBaseID() {
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.w(TAG, "getInstance ID Failed "+task.getException() );
                        return;
                    }
                    String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onComplete:Service Method "+token );

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String call_api=remoteMessage.getData().get("callapi");
    String play_id=remoteMessage.getData().get("play_id");
    String clue_number=remoteMessage.getData().get("clue_number");
    String title=remoteMessage.getData().toString();
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: callapi "+call_api );
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: play_id "+play_id );
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: clue number "+clue_number );
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: title "+title );

    Intent intent= new Intent("remoteMessage");
    intent.putExtra("call_api", call_api);
    intent.putExtra("play_id", play_id);
    intent.putExtra("clue_number", clue_number);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should send with format data, same:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```